# My Developer Story — Let me show it off!

Tags: feature-request, developer-story

The [Developer Story](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2016/10/bye-bye-bullets-the-stack-overflow-developer-story-is-the-new-technical-resume/) isn't just a place for people sifting through resumes. It is a place for developers to show off our accomplishments and to share what we're working on alongside with what we do online.

Without violating any sense of "interfering with the Q&A", it seems like we can better raise awareness of our developer stories by highlighting it as *part* of the flair itself.

**If you have a Developer Story, let us illustrate our hard work in our flair.** If you prefer not to, you can opt out, but the crux of this request is to provide an unobtrusive way to say, *"read my stuff; there's more to this user than meets the eye."*

This is in line with "show, don't just tell."

[image: Developer Story]

Don't worry about my design work or placement; this is merely illustrative. The designers at Stack Exchange can make this beautiful.

If someone doesn't want their Story highlighted on Stack Overflow, **users can simply opt out**; but if the Developer Story goes the way I hope, this can become a great place to keep your virtual portfolio of stuff you are passionate about…  even if you're *not* currently looking for a job.

Comment: Adds fuel to the fire :D Great suggestion.

Comment: "The designers at Stack Exchange can make this beautiful" - I hope so. Yours is ORANGE!!!

Comment: @ThomasWeller - That is to alert other job hunters of your presence.

Comment: Perhaps this could be added to the user menu as well (you know, that expando popout that no one looks at).

Comment: I would also propose adding an indicator for users to inform recruiters whether or not they're open to invitations/offers. You would then hover over it for a tooltip that says, "This developer is [not] accepting invitations at this time." Maybe a lightbulb that's lit if the doors are opened, and dim when it's not.

Comment: If I were a recruiter and found myself on a page where a SO had included the flair snippet, no book icon or other icon would make me say "I should read their stuff; there's more to this user than meets the eye." I guess that isn't a point _against_ adding it, but it's hard for me to see it having the effect you're hoping for

Comment: @henry Then again, what does that big number mean? or those little "yellow", "grey", and "orange" dots with numbers next to them? Icons and alert symbols simply draw attention that there's something significant here; a feature or notification to check out. They usually *can't* be entirely self-evident; it's just not practical.

Comment: @RobertCartaino absolutely, the flair graphic is profoundly uninformative for anyone not SO-fluent. Not at all opposed to adding another little symbol, maybe even with an extra dimension meaningful fill color, I just wouldn't expect it to come across as extra impressive

Comment: Who actually uses the flair? It's a monstrosity in its current form. Don't even get me started on the "hotdog" theme one. Ugh. I died a little inside when I saw that.

Comment: I think you should be able to opt in if you want it - the default is OPT-OUT.

Comment: @RobertCartaino just so I'm clear, the suggestion is to create a flair that links to your Developer Story?

Comment: @Kit No, just to indicate that you have one.

Comment: I removed the [status-review] tag from this post because the Jobs product no longer exists.