# Show me how many views my developer story has received

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, developer-story, views

I would like to be able to see how many times my [Developer Story](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336069/my-developer-story-let-me-show-it-off) has been viewed.

Even better would be:

- Views in story vs traditional mode
- Views per referrer (filterable by date)
- Let me create multiple unique links to my dev story, and show many clicks each has received

Comment: Let's call it "Developer Story Analytics"

Comment: I wonder if you can also split that between potential employers, general SE users and random people from the internet?

Answer (score 28):

Some points which I think are important:

- Since the employer who visited my profile can't be disclosed (*I am assuming so*), It would be better if I can see analytics based on location like city or town.
- Site from where my profile has been visited.

Answer (score 13):

I believe that most people who are actively looking for a job on Stack Overflow or those who are interested in who is viewing their Developer Story would appreciate having access to this information.

Realistically, there aren’t any privacy implications by giving the owner of the story access to such information through a web based interface, although others users should not be able to view this information.

As for what information should be captured, I believe the following is a reasonable guide:

- Amount of views
- Viewing location (as in, the country where the
  person is browsing from)
- Type of viewer (whether the viewer is
  someone on the web, a logged in SE user, or an employer)
- Referrer (what site the link was on)

The third point might not be necessary, but all the other information should be presented in the appropriate graphs and tables, filterable by dates. I imagine this to become a very simple version of Google Analytics.

As for your third point, this would have to link in with the referrer. If SO could get some kind of link generator for Developer Stories, that would be excellent. An alternative method could be as follows:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/users/story/<user id>?ref_id=561872346
```

Here, you can see that this is a regular Developer Story URL, but with the extra `ref_id` on the end. I envision an area where you could generate a new URL with a unique id, and use that URL for whatever purpose you envisage. You could then assign a name to the specific URL within Stack Overflow.

Obviously, there would be a separate option to generate the above URL for the traditional view.

The following are a few quick mock-ups that demonstrate what I am trying to show. They are all my own work unless when the description says otherwise. Feel free to use them for any purpose, but please give attribution when doing so:

[image: tab]

> Perhaps a special tab for analytics?

[image: view chart]

> Perhaps a view counter something like the reputation counter?

[image: location heat map]

> Perhaps a viewing location heat map like this? (map from bit.ly/2ejsEbK)

[image: 3 circles graph]

> Perhaps a chart like this to show who is looking at your profile (icons are from Apple's Color Emoji Font)

[image: table of referrers]

> Perhaps a table something like this (with more detail)

[image: referrer name assignment]

> Perhaps a dialog like this when generating a new URL?

Please, let me know your thoughts!

Disclaimer: I draw freehand circles just for the memes